# Nautilus-Actions Is Adding Backslash

Tags: command-line, terminal, nautilus

I am trying to add a right click menu to [odrive](https://docs.odrive.com/docs/odrive-sync-agent), using `nautilus-actions` and the sync agent.

However, after setting the script up with the path `"$HOME/.odrive-agent/bin/odrive"` and parameters `sync "%f"` (Like shown in the documentation).

This does not work, and setting it to show output gives me

`"$HOME/.odrive-agent/bin/odrive" sync "\"/home/username/odrive-agent-mount/Dropbox/Documents.cloudf"\""`

The proper command is supposed to be

`"$HOME/.odrive-agent/bin/odrive" sync "$HOME/odrive-agent-mount/Dropbox/Documents.cloudf"`

How do I make it so that the `\` is removed from within `nautilus-actions`

Comment: I haven't used this, but have you tried just `%f`?

Comment: Yeahh... that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `%f`, don't add double quotes around it. Doing so will prompt the application to escape the double quotes in the string (that's where the backslashes comes from).

Comment: Well that was easy.....